# Where to define views, constraints and targets when not using the StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift

I did some research but I could not find an appropriate answer regarding the following question.

I don't use the interface builder to generate my views so every control is defined programmatically like so :

```
let loginButton: UIButton = {
  let button = UIBUtton()
  button.setTitle("Title", forState: .Normal)
  // adding some properties to my button
  return button
}()
```

Then I add it to the view of my `ViewController` like that :

```
self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

And I add some constraints with the `Visual Format Language`

For example :

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat
_("V:|[v0(25)]|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, 
_views: ["v0":loginButton]))
```

It works really well and I prefer it that way(over the IB) but the main issue is that I end up with really big `ViewController` classes as I define every controls in the ViewControllers classes.

I guess I should have all the controls declarations, constraints,... in a separate file but I can't find how to do that.

I tried to create a separate class, for example `LoginView`, which contains all the controls, and a function `setupViews(superView: UIView)` that adds `subviews` to the `superView` parameter and specify constraints. Then in the `viewDidLoad()` method of my `ViewController`, I instantiate this class (`LoginView`) and execute the `setupView(superView: self.view)`. It looks like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginView = LoginView()
        loginView.setupViews(self.view)

    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this is not the way to go. It also causes problems when I try to `addTarget` to some of my controls.

My question, what is the best way to do it, following the MVC pattern.
Thank you very much !

EDIT 1 :

As asked in the comments, here is the implementation of the LoginView class (I only kept few controls/constraints to keep it short but it is the same process for every other one)

```
import UIKit

class LoginView {

 let superView: UIView?

 init(tempSuperView: UIView){
  superView = tempSuperView
 }

 let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
  let textField = UITextField()
  textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  textField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

  return textField
 }()

 let loginButton: UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton()
  button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  button.setTitle("Login", forState: .Normal)

 return button
 }()

 //some more controls definition

 func setupViews() -> Void {

 superView!.addSubview(usernameTextField)
 superView!.addSubview(loginButton)

 superView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat
_("V:|-150-[v0(50)]", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, 
_views: ["v0":usernameTextField]))
 superView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat
_("H:|-150-[v0(25)]", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, 
_views: ["v0":usernameTextField]))

 //same for the button
 }
}
```

Here is my ViewController :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginView = LoginView(tempSuperView: self.view)
        loginView.setupViews()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: You should better create a method in your view controller called `setupViews` for example, where you define your layout.
Could you show us the implementation of your LoginView class ?

Comment: This is totally up to you, but keep in mind that you can't define properties in an extension of a class, so your properties will have to be on the main declaration.
I usually have a `generateConstraints` function, but I usually use IB, and I always try to keep my ViewController classes small.

Comment: @Randy Thanks for your comment, I added the code you asked. At first I did the way you proposed but at the end, you still have a big "ugly" function in your ViewController

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thanks for your answer, I guess some ways are better than others so do you have like an example of source code I could look at to see how you or other people did it ?